# How to wait for another process till it finish in Linux using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, dpkg

I am trying to install sshpass on Ubuntu machine.

I am getting the following error when I try to install sshpass on Ubuntu.

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Following are the methods for finding process using /var/lib/dpkg/lock

1. Find process using lsof for /var/lib/dpkg/lock

   sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock

> ```
> COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
> apt     93785 root    4uW  REG    8,1        0 56743 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
> ```

2. Find process using fuser for /var/lib/dpkg/lock

> ```
>  sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock
>
> /var/lib/dpkg/lock:  93785
> ```

I am trying the following to fetch only process id. But I am getting the following result and unable to fetch the process id.

> sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock | awk -F: '{print $1}'

/var/lib/dpkg/lock:
   93785

I want to wait till process which is holding the /var/lib/dpkg/lock to be finished. How can I achieve using shell script?

Comment: If there was some problem like machine shutdown during previous installation. There might be unwanted locking which was not freed. So, you might try deleting the lock file as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/102084).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
wait $!
```

It will wait for previous command.